# Spring Security 5 return 403 on login

Tags: spring-security

I am evaluating Spring 5 (MVC) and Spring Security 5.
When I am posting username and password from a custom form I get a 403 return code.
When using  instead of  or the Spring default login form everything is workin fine.

Here my applicationContext-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
     xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http auto-config='false' use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/assets/**" access="isAnonymous() or hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/**" access="isAnonymous() or hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.do**" access="isAnonymous() or hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app2/**" access="isAnonymous() or hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <form-login login-page="/index.do#/login"
                login-processing-url="/login"
                default-target-url="/index.do"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Include the `csrf` token in your request, make sure you have that in your page.

Comment: That's it. Thanks alot!